# Problem with catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

When I want to use catkin_make I get the next problem.

```
pi@cctronics ~/catkin_ws $ catkin_make
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.topological_order import topological_order" failed: No module named tool_detection
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTOHNPATH
```

I don't know how to fix the issue.

Currently I'm using ROS Indigo on Raspberry Pi.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233190/problem-with-catkin_make/) by [LogicRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/26520/logicros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't worry for answering U.U

I thing that i have the solution in the next link.   http://wiki.ros.org/catkin_pkg

I used

```
sudo pip install -U catkin_pkg
```

---

Originally posted by [LogicRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/26520/logicros/) with karma: 26 on 2016-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0